# Cannot Intospect reference token by other client

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have IDS4 (resource `ids`) with users on single host

```
options.ApiName = "ids";
options.ApiSecret = "secret";
```

and client (clientId `cl1`) with PasswordFlowCredentials.
Client has scope `ids`.

When I get JWT token with login-password by `cl1` I have access to controllers on `ids`. But if I get reference token I cannot access.

Introspection endpoint return 401 because `client_id=ids` but token from `cl1`.
`token=15cf93dd255db79a46141c9403f86a71f81d797b2e7649bdd56e10f860c9afde&client_id=ids&token_type_hint=access_token&client_secret=secret`

Token content from PersistedGrants (short)

```
    {"CreationTime":"2019-01-11T11:12:37Z","Lifetime":900000,"AccessToken":
    {"Audiences":
    ["https://localhost:5000/resources","ids"],
    "Issuer":"https://localhost:5000","CreationTime":"2019-01-11T11:12:37Z",
    "Lifetime":90000,"Type":"access_token","ClientId":"cl1",
    "AccessTokenType":1,"Claims":
    [{"Type":"client_id","Value":"cl1","ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"},
    {"Type":"scope","Value":"ids","ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"},
    {"Type":"sub","Value":"5eb745a6-21ab-4f69-941d-0295f9a9e468","ValueType":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"},
```

Where is error?

How can I validate reference token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client_id` in introspection request is not `client_id`. There is must be `Resource Id` from `[dbo].[ApiResources]` and secret from `[dbo].[ApiSecrets]`